# Dired+ : Not change foreground color of compress files

Tags: dired, faces, customize-face

Emacs 27.1

package [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus), Version: 2023.01.14

Here screen

[image]

As you can see the foreground of suffix compress file is correct (orange). Nice.

But the foreground of name compress file **is not change** (must be blue).

Why?

Answer (score 2):

Put your cursor on a colored character and use `C-x =`. Near the bottom of buffer `*Help*` you'll see the faces used for that character.

Use `M-x customize-face` to customize any face. Save your changes (in Customize).

On the suffix for a compressed file, `C-x =` tells me this:

```
There are text properties here:
  dired-filename       t
  face                 diredp-compressed-file-suffix
  fontified            t
  help-echo            diredp-mouseover-help
  mouse-face           highlight
```

On the base file name (not the suffix), `C-x =` tells me this:

```
There are text properties here:
  dired-filename       t
  face                 diredp-compressed-file-name
  fontified            t
  help-echo            diredp-mouseover-help
  mouse-face           highlight
```

`M-x customize-face RET diredp-compressed-file-name RET` will tell you how that face is currently defined, and let you change its appearance.

---

***However***, option `diredp-ignore-compressed-flag` controls this also, and by default it is non-`nil`:

> **`diredp-ignore-compressed-flag`** is a variable defined in [`dired+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/dired%2b.el).
>
> Its value is `t`
>
> Documentation:
>
> Non-`nil` means to **font-lock names of compressed files as ignored files**.
>
> This applies to filenames whose extensions are in
> `diredp-compressed-extensions`.  If `nil` they are highlighted using
> face `diredp-compressed-file-name`.
>
> Note: If you change the value of this option then you need to restart
> Emacs to see the effect of the new value on font-locking.
>
> You can customize this variable.

So if `diredp-ignore-compressed-flag` is non-`nil` then the face you might want to customize is **`diredp-ignored-file-name`**.  (And in that case, `*Help*` will have told you that that's the face used on the base file name.)

---

The Dired+ doc (see the Commentary in file `dired+.el`, for instance) tells you:

> You can use key **`C-down`** or **`C-up`** to navigate to the next or
> previous file line, respectively, and at the same time show its
> file in another window.  The focus remains on the Dired buffer.
> A numeric prefix arg means move that many lines first.
>
> Names of files and directories that match either of the options
> **`diredp-visit-ignore-extensions`** or `diredp-visit-ignore-regexps` are skipped.

This is one reason that compressed files are "ignored", by default: when cycling among files in a listing using, say, `C-down`, you generally might not want to open compressed files. If this is the case then you will want to add their extensions (e.g. `Z`, `tgz`, etc.) to the value of option `diredp-visit-ignore-extensions`.

---

**UPDATE** after your comment:

You added a comment that says that your `diredp-ignore-compressed-flag` is `nil`, but (I guess?) you're still seeing its non-`nil` effect.

Your saying only this tells us nothing helpful:

```
"C-x =" - Char: m (109, #o155, #x6d) point=947 of 1210 (78%) column=49
```

You need to look at the **bottom of the `*Help*` buffer**, to see what face is being used there. See what I wrote and show, above.

I'm guessing you didn't **save** the `nil` value after changing option `diredp-ignore-compressed-flag` to `nil` with `M-x customize-option`. Or if you did, you didn't start a new Emacs session to see the effect.

Did you read this part of the `dired+.el` Commentary?

```
;;  A few of the user options defined here have an effect on
;;  font-locking, and this effect is established only when Dired+ is
;;  loaded, which defines the font-lock keywords for Dired.  These
;;  options include `diredp-compressed-extensions',
;;  `diredp-ignore-compressed-flag', `dired-omit-extensions', and
;;  `diredp-omit-files-font-lock-regexp'.  This means that if you
;;  change the value of such an option then you will see the change
;;  only in a new Emacs session.
```

In other words, you need to (1) change the option value to `nil`, (2) **save** that change, and (3) start a new Emacs session to see the effect of the change.

Comment: "Diredp Ignore Compressed Flag" is nil. But it not help. Compress file name not set to blue color. "C-x =" - Char: m (109, #o155, #x6d) point=947 of 1210 (78%) column=49